# How to reorder tableview cell and save state of the cell after reorder

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a tableview cell which consist of one menu button icon -> menutitle -> eyeImage. How do I reorder the cell and save the state of the cell after reorder? I have two arrays for menuicons and menutitles.

My two arrays:-

```
var menuTitlesArr = ["Portfolio","Moves & Alerts","Market Analysis","Chats","]
var menuIconsArr = ["portfolio","cal","news","chat","more"]
```

My screenshot:-
image for my tableview cell:

[image: image for my tableview cell]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can start using [UserDefault](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults), you can save the array using it

```
import Foundation

// Access Shared Defaults Object
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

// Create and Write Array of Strings
let array = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "myKey")

// Read/Get Array of Strings
let strings = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myKey")
```

Then, when you change the cells order, set it again

```
let array = ["Two", "One", "Three"]
userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "myKey")
```

For something more advanced I like to use the [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) for local storage

Comment: can you give me a demo sir

Comment: The obvious problem is that the array is static. Every time you instantiate the ViewController, the array will be the same. The idea is that you start learning how to save information locally in the devise.